# Is there a non trivial smooth function that has uncountably many roots?

Tags: analysis

(on a bounded domain).
I believe that such a function could not exist since every $C^\infty$ function can be approximated by a sequence of polynomials and every polynomial has a finite number of roots so it would not be possible for something that vanishes countably often to converge to something that vanishes uncountably often.

Comment: How about a compactly supported function ?

Comment: Your polynomial approximation idea works the same way if the function is only assumed to be continuous, and such a function can be zero on $(-1,0)$ and $=x$ on $[0,1)$

Comment: And so with $g(x)=e^{-1/(x(1-x))})1_{x\in [0,1]}$ you can also construct a smooth function $\phi\in C^\infty(0,1),\phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}\sum_{a\in \{0,2\}^n} g(3^{n+1} (x-3^{-n-1}-\sum_{m=1}^n a_m 3^{-m})$ vanishing only at the Cantor set, which is not a countable union of points and closed intervals.

Comment: Your claim that a sequence of functions with only countably many zeros cannot converge to a sequence with uncountably many zeros is also wrong: Take the sequence of constant functions $f_n(x) = 1/n$.

Answer (score 13):

The following function is $C^\infty$ on ${\bf R}$ and is zero outside the unit interval.
$$
f(x) = e^{-{1\over 1-x^2}}{\bf 1}_{[-1,1]}(x)
$$
Such function is called a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Answer (score -3):

$x  \sin (1/x) $

This function has a sequence of roots tending to zero.

[image]

Comment: The question asked for an uncountable set of roots.

Comment: @CarstenS I see.